# Finding the largest angle of a triangle

Tags: triangles

The sides of a triangle are $(x^2+x+1), (2x+1)$ and $(x^2-1)$. Then what is the largest of the 3 angles of triangle?

Comment: The largest angle of any triangle is the angle opposite the longest side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x>0$. As $(x^{2}-1)$ is a side of the triangle then $x^{2}-1>0$ , therefore $x>1$.
Note that
$(x^{2}+x+1)-(x^{2}-1)=x+2>0$, then $(x^{2}+x+1)>(x^{2}-1)$. Another hand, as $x>1$,
$(x^{2}+x+1)-(2x+1)=x^{2}-x>0$. Therefore $(x^{2}+x+1)$ is the largest side of the triangle. The largest angle is the opposite to the side $(x^{2}+x+1).$

As $(x^{2}+x+1)$ is the largest side of the triangle, by the law of cosines,
$$(x^{2}+x+1)^{2}=(2x+1)^{2}+(x^{2}-1)-2(2x+1)(x^{2}-1)\cos\theta$$
Therefore $\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{2}$, then $\theta=120^{\circ}$.

Comment: Yeah, right!
This is similar to the approach with vectors.

Comment: You're _assuming_ $X > 0$, but this is not necessary. Since all sides can be supposed to larger than $0$, this means that from $x^2-1>0$ it follows that $x>1\bigvee x<-1$. Also, from $2x+1>0$ follows that $x > -\tfrac{1}{2}$. Taking these together, we have $x>1$, without assuming anything.